# Debug object is undefined

Tags: phaser-framework

I have looked at a bunch of different examples of peoples code and they are using something like:

```
this.game.debug
```

I have probably 20 combinations e.g.

```
this.game.debug
this.scene.debug, 
this.scene.game.debug
```

etc.. but cannot find this debug, can anyone guide me on where to find this debug object?

Comment: Is you question about debugging of physics?
http://labs.phaser.io/edit.html?src=src%5Cphysics%5Carcade%5Csimple%20body.js

Comment: that works great thank you

Comment: Happy to help ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Phaser 3 comes with physics debugger, that can be enabled by configuration.

```js
var config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    parent: 'phaser-example',
    physics: {
        default: 'arcade',
        arcade: {
            debug: true,
            gravity: { y: 200 }
        }
    },
    scene: {
        preload: preload,
        create: create
    }
};

var game = new Phaser.Game(config);
```

[Here](http://labs.phaser.io/edit.html?src=src%5Cphysics%5Carcade%5Csimple%20body.js) a working example, that gives you something like this:

[image]